# Create Directory and give user FullControl problem

Tags: c#

I am having a problem creating a directory with specific permissions.

```
        //Make sure Tools directory exists
        DirectoryInfo oMyDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(oInstance.szToolsPath);
        if (!oMyDirectoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            oMyDirectoryInfo.Create();
            DirectorySecurity oDirectorySecurity = oMyDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
            oDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule((Settings.Default.LoginDomain + "\\" + Settings.Default.LoginUsername), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
            oMyDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(oDirectorySecurity);
        }
```

Now this creates the directory and I can see that the Login has been added to the security tab. However when I Impersonate the Login and try and copy files to that directory I get a Unauthorized Exception. I can create a file (no data), I can create a folder but I cannot write data to files (but I set FullControl :/)

I dug further in to the permissions through Windows and I see that it applies to subfolders but I would like to set this to files too. How do I do this through code?

This is on Windows 7

Comment: Is this code running with an admin user account with UAC disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are creating your `FileSystemAccessRule`, you are specifying `InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit`.  This propagates the mask to child *containers*.  If you want to apply to leaf objects (files in your case), you need to specify `InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit`, or for both,

```
 InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add access rule

```
string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;
            DirectorySecurity dirService = Directory.GetAccessControl(directory + hexID);
            FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName,FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);

            dirService.AddAccessRule(fsa);//add
            Directory.SetAccessControl(directory + hexID, dirService);
```

and use this to remove access rule

```
string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;
            DirectorySecurity dirService = Directory.GetAccessControl(directory + hexID);
            FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);

            dirService.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);//remove
            Directory.SetAccessControl(directory + hexID, dirService);
```